# Infix % operator works in Playground, but not in included Swift library

Tags: swift, swift-playground, xcplayground

I'm trying to overload the % operator for doubles in Swift. I realize the reason that the two methods on the Double type exist, but `truncatingRemainder()`'s behavior works fine for my use case.

I'm using Xcode Playgrounds to work through this problem and I thought I had it solved.

```
infix operator %

func % (left: Double, right: Double) -> Double {
    return left.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: right)
}

var x = 0.0

for _ in 0...5 {
    print(x)
    x = (x + 1.5) % 5.0
}

print(x)
```

This works fine and gives me the correct expected behavior.

After this, I tried putting it into a library I am working on. I created a new .swift file, rebuilt the library, ensured the import statement was working (by using other functions/methods in my library) in my Playground, and I get the following errors:

- Ambiguous operator declarations found for operator
- Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'Double'
- Operator is not a known binary operator

[image: An Xcode screenshot showing the errors listed above next to the code that's listed above.]

Can anyone explain the difference between putting it in my Playground and including it in an imported file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the library, you just need to declare your function with public access. no need `infix operator %`. You are doing operator overloading.

```
public func % (left: Double, right: Double) -> Double {
    return left.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: right)
}
```

`infix operator` needed when you are working on Custom Operator. Like `infix operator **`